# How to get ascending order when I enter a number in the output for the following program?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DisplayAsending {
    static int a;
    static int b;
    static int temp=0;
    //static int[] name=new int[a];

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner no=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number:");
    a=no.nextInt();
    number(a);
    System.out.println("asending order: ");
    order(a);
    }
    public static void number(int a) {
         int[] name=new int[a];
        for (int i=0;i<a;i++) {
            Scanner no=new Scanner(System.in);
            b=no.nextInt();
            name[i]=b;
        }
        for(int j=0;j<a;j++) {
            System.out.println("The numbers are:"+name[j]);
        }
}
    public static void order(int b) {
         int[] value=new int[a];
        for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
                if (value[i] > value[j]) {
                    temp = value[i];
                    value[i] = value[j];
                    value[j] = temp;
}
}
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
            System.out.println(value[i]);
    }
}
}
```

My output is

Enter the number:
2
15
4
The numbers are:15
The numbers are:4
asending order: 
0
0

When I entered 3 in the output means I will give 3 values then it will convert into ascending order.

Comment: For a start your arrays are limited in scope to the methods they are declared in.  How about using a field or have `number` return the newly created array.  Secondly, do not instantiate a new `Scanner` for each iteration of the loop.  Then finally search how to do sort an array

Comment: That's is not duplicate, nothing to do with sorting.

Comment: Use this version of code, to read numbers and print them reversed: https://pastebin.com/uj5m9mpN

Comment: Thank you guys for your support i got the answer